# Python Program not being complied by runtime Android Studio

Tags: java, android, python-3.x, android-studio

So I've been trying to execute a python program using runtime in Android Studio. However when the `runtime` method is called, I get the following error: `12576-12576/com.example.anagramsolver I/System.out: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": error=2, No such file or directory`.

I have tried to run `python3 anasolver.py hello` within the Android Studio terminal, however with that, I get the following error: `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'anasolver.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

However when I run `which python3` I get `/usr/local/bin/python3`/. Is the problem due to the python location or something.

Heres where the error occurs: `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python3 anasolver.py " + word);`.

Here's my full android studio code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView resultstv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultsTV);
        Button solvebtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.solvebtn);
        final EditText enterWordTv =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enterWordET);

        solvebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                System.out.println(anagram(getEnterWordTv(enterWordTv)).toString());
                resultstv.setText(anagram(getEnterWordTv(enterWordTv)).toString());

            }
        });
    }


    public String getEnterWordTv(EditText inputFU) {
        String finWord = inputFU.getText().toString();
        return(finWord);
    }

    ArrayList<String> anagram(String sentence){
        ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        File newFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "anasolver.py");
        try {
            String mainPrg = "import sys\nfrom itertools import permutations\nnew_word = str(sys.argv[1])\n\ndef word(word):\n    listed_sentence = word.split(' ')\n    for i in listed_sentence:\n        new_word = i.lower()\n        combos = map(''.join, permutations(new_word, len(i)))\n        for e in combos: \n            print(e)\nword(new_word)";
            System.out.println("prg made");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFile.getAbsolutePath()));
            System.out.println("File created");
            out.write(mainPrg);
            System.out.println("Program written");
            out.close();
            String word = sentence;
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python3 anasolver.py " + word);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String ret;
            while ((ret = in.readLine()) != null){
                results.add(ret);
            }
            System.out.println(results);
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
            return (results);
        }
    }
```

Comment: when you run it in your terminal, it runs using the python interpreter installed in your system but an android device doesn't have python installed so it won't work there.

Comment: @NALIN_yo oh thank you. Is there any other way to run python on an android device.

Comment: You can make an android app using kivy. Or i cannot be sure but Jython can also be useful because android apps can be written in java and Jython can integrate with java and run Python